# Problema con relación de muchos a muchos MongoDB + Node.js

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Tengo un problema con la relacion de muchos a muchos, el problema es que si registro la herramienta a un proyecto, no se visualiza el valor en la tabla de herramientas, y si lo hago viceversa no se visualiza el valor en proyectos, es como si no se asociara los valores y solo se quede en la tabla.

Modelo de proyecto:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('../config/database');
var user = require('./user');
var tool = require('./tool');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema = Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  project_url: { type: String, require: true },
  image: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  tools: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Tool' }]
});

var Project = (module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema));
```

Aqui esta la funcion en el controlador de proyectos:

```
function registerToolInProject(req, res) {
 project = new Project();
 params = req.body;
 console.log(project.tool);
 var d = q.defer();
 projectId = req.params.id;
 Project.findById(projectId, (err, project) => {
    if (err) {
      d.abort(err);
    } else {
      toolId = params.tool;
      console.log('Dentro de el else: ' + toolId);
      project.tools.push(toolId);
      project.save((err, project) => {
       d.resolve(project);
       res.send({ project });
      });
     }
  });
}
```

Modelo de herramientas:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('../config/database');
var Project = require('./project');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ToolSchema = Schema({
  tool: { type: String, required: true },
  project: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' }
});

var Tool = (module.exports = mongoose.model('Tool', ToolSchema));
```

Y aqui esta la funcion dentro de el controlador de herramientas:

```
function enrollToolInProject(req, res) {
  var d = q.defer();
  params = req.body;
  toolId = req.params.id;
  projectId = params.project;
  Tool.findById(toolId, (err, tool) => {
    tool.project = projectId;
    tool.save();
    res.send({ tool });
  });
  return d.promise;
}
```

Cuando agrego la herramienta aparece se muestra en la tabla pero luego cuando veo todos los proyectos no me muestra nada, aqui los datos en postman:

```
"projects": [
    {
        "_id": "5971f32723eeda0bd2248b15",
        "user": "594bea46a2a2420fff7a444b",
        "image": "null",
        "project_url": "google.co.ve",
        "description": "datos interesantes",
        "title": "NUEVO PROYECTO PRUEBA",
        "__v": 0,
        "tools": [],
        "date": "2017-07-21T12:27:19.927Z"
    }
]
```

Y cuando busco la herramienta si parece:

```
{
"tool": {
    "_id": "5971f36023eeda0bd2248b16",
    "tool": "Node.js",
    "__v": 0,
    "project": {
        "_id": "5971f32723eeda0bd2248b15",
        "user": "594bea46a2a2420fff7a444b",
        "image": "null",
        "project_url": "google.co.ve",
        "description": "datos interesantes",
        "title": "NUEVO PROYECTO PRUEBA",
        "__v": 0,
        "tools": [],
        "date": "2017-07-21T12:27:19.927Z"
    }
}
}
```

La unica manera que se visualice es que la agregue en proyectos.

Comment: ¿La línea `console.log('Dentro de el else: ' + toolId);` te muestra el ObjectId de la herramienta?

Answer (score -1):

¡Hola!

No entiendo muy bien la consulta, pero creo que estás confundiendo la forma de trabajar con mongodb.

Recuerda que mongo es una base de datos NoSQL, es decir no relacional.
Estás hablando de tablas, cuando en realidad mongo no usa tablas. Usa colecciones.

Si lo que necesitas es que el proyecto tenga un array con herramientas, primero tienes que agregar la herramienta a su colección y luego "relacionarla" con un ObjectId insertándola dentro del proyecto. Es lo mismo que haces añadiendo el proyecto a la herramienta, pero al contrario.

Ahora bien yo me replantearía que es lo que quieres guardar en cada colección porque si agregas las herramientas al proyecto no veo la necesidad de agregar el proyecto a la herramienta. Ya puedes saber todas las herramientas de dicho proyecto.

Espero que te ayuda =)